# создатьфункцию создающую ul с 3 элементами li. Текст li задать через аргумент всем одинаков. Кол-во li определяется вторым аргум., являющеся числовым

Tags: javascript

```
function createUl(text,ind){
    const list = document.createElement("ul");
    let liul =document.createElement("li");
    list.innerHTML = text;

    document.body.appendChild(list)
    document.body.appendChild(liul)
    for (let i = 0; i < liul.length; i++) {
        const liulElement = liul[i];

    }

}
createUl('hello',5)

    введите сюда код
```

Comment: а вопрос будет или вы кодом хвастаетесь?)

Comment: как минимум внутри функции надо добавить цикл, чтобы li создавать в том количестве, который задан вторым аргументом ind. И соответственно апендить в список

Comment: пытаюсь понять как решить

Comment: в правильном направлении?function createUl(text,ind){
    const list = document.createElement("ul");
    let liul =document.createElement("li");
    list.innerHTML = text;

    document.body.appendChild(list)
    document.body.appendChild(liul)
    for (let i = 0; i < liul.length; i++) {
        const liulElement = liul[i];

    }

}
createUl('hello',5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так решить эту задачу:

```js
function createUl(text, ind) {
  const ul = document.createElement("ul");
  for (let i = 0; i < ind; ++i) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = text;
    ul.append(li)
  }

  const wp = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  wp.append(ul);
}
createUl('hello', 5)
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: вместо textContent можно написать innerHTML?

Comment: @ВВ Если есть непреодолимое желание, тогда можно. :)